# How to add an action when a text is changed in an input box

Tags: jquery

I would like to give an action(check a checkbox automatically) when something is modified in an input textbox.

I m using jquery like this (but it doesn't work :(.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('.val_displayed').on('change', function{
alert('ok');
alert($(this).val());
});
});


<input id='' class='val_displayed' type='text' name='val_displayed' value='0353995' />
<input id='' class='train' type='checkbox' name='train' value='True'  />
```

So what I would like to do is check the checkbox with class train that is in the same  when a user change the value inside the text input with class val_displayed.

here is the fiddler to show it is not working: http://jsfiddle.net/starcraft04/rQ5Gn/

Thanks,

John.

Comment: any error in the console? whether the elements are created dynamically?

Comment: Learn to love the FF or Chrome console. If you used `console.log('ok');` instead of `alert()`, you probably would have caught the syntax errors in your original and the fiddle you posted.

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //missing () after function below
    $('.val_displayed').on('change', function () {
        alert(this.value)
        $(this).next('input[name="train"]').prop('checked', true);
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/L4GtL/)

Comment: Look at my fiddler, I have replaced everything inside the function with an alert('ok'); and even this is not working :(

Comment: @user2040597 you are missing `()` in `('.val_displayed').on('change', function{`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use keyup and paste to detect change before they unfocus

Altered from Arun P Johny's post https://stackoverflow.com/a/22108438/2167896

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //missing () after function below
    $('.val_displayed').on('change keyup paste', function () {
        alert(this.value);
        $(this).next('input[name="train"]').prop('checked', true);
    });
});
```

Comment: woa, paste? Had no idea.